# react native iPhone Plus text lines

Tags: iphone, react-native, native-base

There are lines over all the multiline Text tags in the app.Lines only shows on **iPhone Plus** not on iPad, tab, android or any other device.

Any idea how to fix it? Lines over Text similar to the image below:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
  Image,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  WebView,
  Dimensions,
  Linking,
  ScrollView,
  NetInfo,
  Alert
} from "react-native";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Content,
  Text,
  H3,
  Button,
  Icon,
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  Left,
  Right,
  Body
} from "native-base";

class Test extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>

<View>
<Text> test test test test test test </Text>
</View>

      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

[image]

Comment: Is this happening in real device or simulator.

Comment: on real device only but i resolved this now by adding transparency to all the Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone 7 Plus show lines on text component background, this is react native known issue already reported on github as well. To resolve this add this in style:

```
 backgroundColor: 'transparent',
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not super helpful. It would be ideal to provide an explanation of why this solves the problem.