# Superfluous lines are showing

Tags: react-native

My app is behaving quiet weird on iPhone plus. Superfluous lines are showing. Need help.

I have already tried updating the style but none of it helped.

All the labels and text fields are displaying it.

Comment: Sorry, we won't be able to help you if you don't include the code you have tried in your post. Please read [ask]

Comment: Just add transparency to all the fields. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766927/react-native-iphone-plus-text-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
```

Add it in style.